# Background Image Cross Fade works, but not the very first time it's triggered

Tags: jquery, html, css, meteor, css-transitions

I'm making a background image slideshow by using `opacity` transitions on several overlaid `div`s, and cycling a `top` css class that triggers one individual layer to show up.

Everything is working great, the transition looks really nice, except for the *very first* time the transition occurs. The very first time, the transition is instant rather than cross-fading.

This Meteor `rendered` callback handles moving the `top` class to a new layer every 9 seconds. An interesting quirk here is that the `console.log` happens **before** the first slide disappears, by roughly the amount I set the transition time to. It almost seems as if the transition is *trying* to happen, but just jumps to it's final value at the end of the transition time.

```js
Template.backgroundPictures.rendered = function () {
    Meteor.setInterval(function () {
        // This console log happens BEFORE the first slide disappears.
        console.log('switch');

        var currentSlide = $('.background-slide.top');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next('.background-slide');
        if (nextSlide.length === 0) nextSlide = $('.background-slide').first();

        currentSlide.removeClass('top');
        nextSlide.addClass('top');

    }, 9000);
};
```

This is the markup for the slides. I initialize the first slide with the `top` class, and I've tried this other ways, such as using the jquery command `$('.background-slide).first().addClass('top');` when the page is rendered, but it gives the same results.

```html
<template name="backgroundPictures">
    <div id="hands" class="background-slide top"></div>
    <div id="score" class="background-slide"></div>
</template>
```

Here's my `less` handling this. I've left out display specific things (positioning, etc.) since that's all working just fine.

```less
.generic-transition {
    transition-property:all .5s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out 0s;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-out 0s;
}
.background-slide {
    // Stuff relating to positioning etc.

    opacity: 0;
    &.top {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    &#hands {
        background: url('/handsplaying.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center;
    }
    &#score {
        background: url('/piano.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center;
    }
}
```

Above I have the transition length set to `.5s`, but as I experiment with longer values to look closer at what's happening, it seems to me that the first slide, the one I initialized with the `top` class, isn't fading out, but that the second slide *is* fading in.

Why is this happening? Do transitions work differently when the class names are supplied from html? And if that's the case, why isn't initializing the first slide with jquery giving different results?

I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm working on it right now.... I'll add asap

Comment: Wait, now that I think about it, I have no idea how to create a js fiddle for a meteor project... is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up just being jumpy animations. It seems that the first time *any* animation on the page happens, it jitters, presumably just while it's setting up the environment?

After the site was deployed to a real server, rather than being locally tested, the problem went away.